# What is this array and can I change it to a list?

Tags: python, list

So I was testing a code from python which generated an array

```
x = [[[3,5,10,7]],[[5,4,4,20]],[[9,100,56,7]]]
```

I do not know what kind of an array this is but for the purpose of my code I need that array to just be a list such as

```
x = [[3,5,10,7],[5,4,4,20],[9,100,56,7]]
```

Is there a way to change this? The actually array I have is much bigger having much more indice. I'm just want to see if its possible for the  simpler array shown above

```
 #my_actual_array  [[[10.65568733,  13.84652805,  14.86591625, ...,  50.24303818,        51.95967865,  46.33126068]], [[12.68396473,  10.31947327,   7.9565444 , ...,  29.54590416, 29.96769142,  29.79670525]] [[28.92797089,  24.25578117,  22.36346626, ..., 55.95978546,56.59334183,  57.22693253]]]
```

Comment: Both objects are lists; each with nested lists. No arrays in sight here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're getting is just an list inside a list inside a third list.

You can simplify it to just a list in a list by grabbing the first (and only) element:

```
>>> x = [[[3,5,10,7]],[[5,4,4,20]],[[9,100,56,7]]]
>>> x2 = [a[0] for a in x]
>>> x2
[[3, 5, 10, 7], [5, 4, 4, 20], [9, 100, 56, 7]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this got what I needed precisely.